# Получение нового DataFrame из n-исходных DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Подскажите.

Смысл таков, есть `n`-количество исходных DataFrame'ов одного формата (которые отвечают за разные показатели). Нужно получить `n+1` - ую таблицу по заданной формуле.

Пример:

```
Год   com1 com2 com3 com4 com5
2012    5   11    2    7    7
2013    6   10    5    8    4
2014    7    8    6    9    5
2015    8    9    8    9    5
2016    4    4    4    4    2
```

В исходнике: https://dropmefiles.com/SwXDs. Для простоты три одинаковых таблицы. Так вот, нужно на выходе получить значение соответствующих  ячеек в 4-ой таблице по формуле: (ячейка (1) / (ячейка(2)+ячейка(3) ). Везде должны получиться значения 0,5 (для простоты примера)

```
       com1 com2 com3 com4 com5
2012    0,5  0,5  0,5  0,5  0,5
```

Также если DF будет разрозненным, как сделать так, чтобы код находил нужные ячейки по индексам, а не просто положению в исходном DF
То есть должен быть создан новый DF из выбранных исходных DF, пример написан для упрощения. Столбцов может быть огромное множество.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим что вы прочитали данные в три DataFrame с одинаковой структурой: `d1`, `d2`, `d3`.

Решение:

```
In [313]: tables = [d1, d2, d3]

In [314]: d4 = d1 / sum(tables[1:])

In [315]: d4
Out[315]:
      com1  com2  com3  com4  com5
2012   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5
2013   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5
2014   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5
2015   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5
2016   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5
```

NOTE: это решение не будет работать если имена столбцов или значения индексов не будут совпадать, т.к. Pandas при суммировании и делении делает выравнивание по столбцам и значениям индекса. Если просто поменять местами столбцы - решение должно отработать правильно.

Comment: А если структура не на все 100% будет одинаковой?  Если столбцы местами например будут поменяны. Код сработает?

Comment: Ответы на SO отвечают на конкретно и корректно заданные вопросы. Данное решение отвечает на вопрос с одинаковыми по структуре таблицами. Если это вам не подходит, то задайте новый вопрос с соответствующим примером входных данных ;)